# What would be the best temporary adhesive to stick a shower head holder onto a ceramic tile wall?

Tags: adhesive, ceramic-tile

I recently broke the shower bracket and can't get a replacement since it's out of stock everywhere. I bought a suction cup shower head holder as a temporary fix but that won't stay on the wall so I was thinking of gluing it until I can afford to get the whole shower rail replaced.

What would be the best (but temporary) adhesive to stick a shower head holder onto the wall? I was thinking hot melt from a glue gun since that can be removed fairly easily but I'm worried the humidity and steam from the shower would weaken the bond.

Comment: Hot glue won't likely bond well enough to hold, and the heat may discolor your shower wall. Go with silicone.

Answer (score 5):

Silicone caulk or silicone RTV (Room Temperature Vulcanizing) glue (pretty much the same thing with different labels.) Sticks pretty well, moisture helps it cure, and it can be peeled off when you want it gone.